# Is there any way that we can translate a whole Google Docs file using Google (Apps) Script, BUT still keep all the formats, tables, images intact?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to imitate the "Translate Document" tool in Google Docs by writing a Google (Apps) Script that can automatically translate a series of documents.

I've tried LanguageApp.Translate() but this syntax only returns an unformatted string and removes all the table borders (purely string).

This is my code:

```
function TranslateFunction() {
  //Get the files in your indicated Folder
  var TargetFolderID = '1VUNGtqiNbnHhIFCXmbdSwNZ-vZ5NWVTE'; //Paste the folder ID here to start
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(TargetFolderID);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  //Get all the files' ID in the folder above
  while (files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    var fileID = file.getId();

    //Convert each file in the folder from Docx (Word) to Docs (Google)
    var docx = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
    var newDoc = Drive.newFile();
    var blob = docx.getBlob();
    var file=Drive.Files.insert(newDoc,blob,{convert:true});
    DocumentApp.openById(file.id).setName(docx.getName().slice(0,-5));  

    //Activate the file
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.id);

    //Create a new Docs file to put the translation in + Name
    var newDoc = DocumentApp.create("|EN| " + docx.getName().slice(0,-5)); 
  
    //Get the text in the file
    var bodyText = doc.getBody().getText();

    //Translate the text and append it into the new Docs
    Translatedtext = LanguageApp.translate(bodyText,'vi','en');
    newDoc.getBody().appendParagraph(Translatedtext);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same challenge and what seems to work for me is first creating a copy of the document I'm trying to translate and then looping through all paragraphs and translating them one by one.

In my use case I wanted to coordinate this from a Google Sheet as I mostly need multiple different translations from the same Doc that then need to be reviewed by colleagues, therefore I'd usually put source Doc URLs into a sheet, run a script that translates it to all needed languages and then feeds back the URLs into the sheet.

For source and target language use [ISO-639 codes](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages).

```
function translateDoc (sourceURL, sourceLang, targetLang) {
  // get ID from URL, open file and get ID from the folder it's in
  var sourceDocId = sourceURL.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
  var sourceDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceDocId);
  var sourceTitle = sourceDoc.getName();
  var sourceFolderId = sourceDoc.getParents().next().getId();

  // create a copy in the same folder and indicate the language in the title
  var targetTitle = "[" + String(targetLang).toUpperCase() + " translation] " + sourceTitle;
  var targetDoc = sourceDoc.makeCopy(targetTitle, DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId));

  // open copied Doc and start looping through the content
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(targetDoc.getId());
  var body = doc.getBody();

  var elements = body.getParagraphs();

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var translatedText = LanguageApp.translate(element.getText(), sourceLang, targetLang);
    if(translatedText != "") element.setText(translatedText);
    // I had an error with an empty paragraph, so avoiding this by only updating when not empty
  }
  doc.saveAndClose();
  return "https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + targetDoc.getId(); // returns URL of translated doc
}

function translateDocs () {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var languages = ["de", "fr", "es", "it", "nl", "pl", "pt"];
  var sourceFileURL, translationDoc;

  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    if (index === 0) return; // table headers
    if (row[0] == "") return; // no source file
    if (row[1] != "") return; // column 2 not empty --> already translated this file

    sourceFileURL = row[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < languages.length; i++) {
      translationDoc = translateDoc(sourceFileURL, "en", languages[i]);
      sheet.getDataRange().getCell(parseInt(index) + 1,parseInt(i) + 2).setValue(translationDoc);
    }
  });
}
```